# How to connect to MongoDB with Async/Await in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, database-connection

I have a Connection class with static methods that allows me to create a singleton type object for MongoDB connections. Using Async along with Await, I never get the connection to 'fire' before the rest of my code executes.

Using the traditional Promise / .then this Connection class works. Using Latest Nodejs version and MongoDB version.

```
static connectDb() {
    //If MongoDB is already connected, return db object
    if (this.dbClient) {
      //const currDbClient = Promise.resolve(this.dbClient);
      console.log(`MongoDB already connected!`);
      return this.dbClient;
    }
    //Otherwise connect
    else {
      async () => {
        try {
          const newDbClient = await MongoClient.connect(this.url, this.options);
          console.log(`DB is connected? ${newDbClient.isConnected()}`);
          ConnectMeCore.dbClient = newDbClient;
          return newDbClient;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`MongoDB connection failed with > ${error}`);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

I expect the await to 'wait' for the DB to connect, or at least resolve the promise.

Comment: are you saying `console.log(\`DB is connected? ${newDbClient.isConnected()}\`);` doesn't wait for the connection *"to fire"*?

Comment: Does `connect()` return a promise or is it a callback type function? If its the later there wouldnt be anything to `await` so code continues on

Comment: @JaromandaX console.log(`DB is connected? ${newDbClient.isConnected()}` never gets called, so the const newDbClient = await MongoClient.connect(this.url, 
        this.options); line  'seems' to not be returning before the remaining code outside of this try block finishes.

Comment: @PatrickEvans MongoClient.connect returns a Promise, but instead of using the Promise / .then pattern, I wanted to use async await. As stated, I can get the Promise / ,then pattern to work fine.

Comment: `code outside of this try block` there is no code outside the try block - except for the catch block - does that run? Perhaps you're using async/await incorrectly - it's hard to say when all you post is a fragment of code that wont even execute

Comment: does a `console.log('before')` in the line BEFORE the await execute (I'm guessing it actually wont

Comment: @JaromandaX The template on this site said only add fragments, not the entire code. The only relevant code is this try catch block. If no one can point to working MongoDB code that uses Async Await connection code from a context of a singleton, maybe it's not supported.

Comment: Updated to include the entire method for clarity

Comment: `he template on this site said only add fragments, not the entire code` sure, but the fragment you posted doesn't show how it is used :p - that bit of code won't even run - put a console.log as the first line inside the `async () => {` to prove it

Comment: you'll want something like https://pastebin.com/WRk8TWUh ... note, you'll ALWAYS want to return a promise, you can't return a Promise in one branch of code and return a value in the other - makes calling the function more complex than it needs to be - if it always returns a Promise, then you use await or .then when using it - it'd be interesting to see the working Promise/.then version and how you got this version so wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX you made the whole static method in the class async, I will try this. And yes... I can return a Promise in the first block > const currDbClient = Promise.resolve(this.dbClient);

Comment: well, yes, because in the else block you wouldn't be able to return anything BUT a promise anyway (that's how asynchrony works) - so, to be consistent, the whole function needs to return a promise (be async)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. I get that the whole method needs to return a Promise, however you are saying you still need to handle the Promise on the return with Async/Await? You can replace all your Promise/.then code with the Async/Await(which is more readable, no Pyramid of Doom). Clarify why the Promise even matters in this connectDb example?

Comment: in your esle code you have `const newDbClient = await MongoClient.connect` therefore you are awaiting the promise returned by `MongoClient.connect` - therefore, the only sensible thing this can return is a Promise (async/await is just syntax sugar for Promises) - since the else branch returns a Promise, it makes no sense for the if branch not to - as I said, it would mean the *calling* code would require if/else ... etc... having the function return a Promise means that the *calling* code just needs to use async/await (or .then - same thing, different syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JaromandaX for helping find the answer!

The calling code can use a Promise.then to execute code once the DB connection happens.

```
DbConnection.connectDb().then(() => {
      console.log("Is it connected? " + DbConnection.isConnected());
      //Do CRUD
      DbConnection.closeDb();
    });
```

You can import this method(as part of 'Connection' class) into any class that needs to have a DB connect. A singleton for on DB connection. The working method fragment is as follows.

```
  static async connectDb() {
    //If MongoDB is already connected, return db object
    if (this.dbClient) {
      const currDbClient = Promise.resolve(this.dbClient);
      console.log(`MongoDB already connected!`);
      return currDbClient;
    }
    //Otherwise connect using 'await', the whole methos is async
    else {
      try {
        const newDbClient = await MongoClient.connect(this.url, this.options);
        console.log(`DB is connected? ${newDbClient.isConnected()}`);
        this.dbClient = newDbClient;
        return newDbClient;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`MongoDB connection failed with > ${error}`);
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
```